# Which is the structure of the path in the case of query request?

Tags: node.js, api, hapi.js

I'm using hapi.js  but one thing is not clear for me. In the case I make api request passing params in the path,  I could get these ones by calling request.params in the handler. When I do request in the form of query what should be the path? In the first case I place in the path property something like /{param}  but in the second one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `request.query`. Four properties hold request data:

- `headers`: the raw request headers (references `request.raw.headers`).
- `params`: an object where each key is a path parameter name with matching value.
- `payload`: the request payload based on the route `payload.output` and `payload.parse` settings.
- `query`: an object containing the query parameters.

You can find more information in the [API Reference](http://hapijs.com/api#request-properties).

**Edit:** Here is an example:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server(3000);

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    console.log(request.query.example);
  }
});

server.start(function () {
  console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

If you visit `http://localhost:3000/?example=hapi`, it will log `hapi` to the console.

Comment: ok I know those things but what should I put on path field? Can you made an exmaple?

Comment: Added an example, hope it helps.